# Remove multiple strings at a time in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove 'hi' ,'by', 'dy' from col2 at one shot in sql. I'm very new to sql server, if anyone could give an outline how such problems are solved that would be really helpful.

```
Col1 col2 col3

A  hi!abcd   123
B  bypython 678
C   norm    888
D  dupty dy 999

output:
Col1 col2 col3

A  abcd   123
B  python 678
C   norm   888
D  dupty   999
```

Comment: You can use `REPLACE` function for this

Comment: i've used REPLACE but my problem how can i add more than one string at a time in REPLACE if that works

Comment: You can use it multiple times like this `REPLACE(REPLACE(mycol, 'hi', ''), 'by', '')`

Comment: thanks for the info, appreciate it! But is there a smarter way to do it using an OR condition or something?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos `TRANSLATE` in SQL Server 2017